# Reference a public static class in the global namespace in another assembly

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, .net-assembly

In C#, is there a way to access a public static class in the global namespace in assembly A from assembly B (assuming assembly B references assembly A), **when assembly B has public static class in the global namespace that has the same name**?  For example in `Bar.cs` in assembly A:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
// NOTE: No namespace declared here - this is in the global:: ns
public static class Bar
{
    public static void DoSomethingSilly()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I'm silly!");
    }
}
```

How could I use this in `Bar.cs` in assembly B?

```
public static class Bar
{
    public static void DoSomethingSilly()
    {
        // call Bar.DoSomethingSilly() from assembly A here
    }
}
```

I tried things like `global::Bar.DoSomethingSilly()`, which doesn't work in assembly B (it just gets me the reference back to assembly B).

I also know I could use reflection to get at it (something like `Assembly.GetType()`), but I'm more wondering if there's some native C# syntax for it.  In the end I added a namespace around the code in assembly A, which I own and which was only in the global namespace because it was generated by another tool - adding the namespace didn't cause any problems, but I'm curious if there's syntax to allow this kind of referencing.

Comment: It should be absolutely fine in assembly B. No extra syntax required. Will double check by actually doing it, but there should be no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Ahhh, I forgot to mention a particular wrinkle... Assembly B has another static class with the same name.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Also in the global namespace? In that case, [extern alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is what you're after.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jon Skeet for this direction - extern alias is what can make this work.  On the properties for the reference to the assembly, add an alias (for example `assemblyA`, or in the screen shot taken from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ansonh/2006/09/27/extern-alias-walkthrough/) `FooVersion1`):

[image: property window example]

, and at the top of the .cs file add:

```
extern alias assemblyA;
```

which will then allow either:

```
assemblyA::Foo.DoSomethingSilly();
assemblyA.Foo.DoSomethingSilly();
```

I still went for adding a namespace to the generated code - it's more straightforward and avoids polluting the global namespace.